# Tips on refactoring EF query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dapper

This query takes almost **40** seconds *(runs 3 times at startup...)*:

```
return context.Audits
        .Include(a => a.Phases.Select(p => p.UserActionLogs))
        .Include(a => a.Phases.Select(p => p.Reminders))
        .Include(a => a.Phases.Select(p => p.PhaseType))
        .Include(a => a.AuditResources.Select(ar => ar.Resource))
        .Include(a => a.AuditCostCenterManagers.Select(acm => acm.CostCenterManager))
        .Include(a => a.AuditResources.Select(ar => ar.ResourceOwners.Select(ro => ro.Owner)))
        .Include(a => a.AuditResources.Select(ar => ar.UserFiles.Select(uf => uf.UserLists)))
        .Include(a => a.AuditType)
        .Where(a => a.Id == context.Audits.Max(aa => aa.Id) && a.EndDate == null).SingleOrDefault();
```

The callers rely on the child objects. How can I make it more performant whilst delivering all the required child objects? I'm using **EF 6.1.40302.0** in a **.Net 4.6.1** WPF project. I'd like to introduce Dapper but I don't see how I can do this kind of complex query in Dapper.

**Raw SQL:** (yummy)

```
SELECT 
    [UnionAll4].[Id] AS [C1], 
    [UnionAll4].[Id1] AS [C2], 
    [UnionAll4].[Description] AS [C3], 
    [UnionAll4].[UserId] AS [C4], 
    [UnionAll4].[BeginDate] AS [C5], 
    [UnionAll4].[EndDate] AS [C6], 
    [UnionAll4].[Deadline] AS [C7], 
    [UnionAll4].[AuditTypeId] AS [C8], 
    [UnionAll4].[Id2] AS [C9], 
    [UnionAll4].[Description1] AS [C10], 
    [UnionAll4].[C1] AS [C11], 
    [UnionAll4].[C2] AS [C12], 
    [UnionAll4].[C3] AS [C13], 
    [UnionAll4].[C4] AS [C14], 
    [UnionAll4].[C5] AS [C15], 
    [UnionAll4].[C6] AS [C16], 
    [UnionAll4].[C7] AS [C17], 
    [UnionAll4].[C8] AS [C18], 
    [UnionAll4].[C9] AS [C19], 
    [UnionAll4].[C10] AS [C20], 
    [UnionAll4].[C11] AS [C21], 
    [UnionAll4].[C12] AS [C22], 
    [UnionAll4].[C13] AS [C23], 
    [UnionAll4].[C14] AS [C24], 
    [UnionAll4].[C15] AS [C25], 
    [UnionAll4].[C16] AS [C26], 
    [UnionAll4].[C17] AS [C27], 
    [UnionAll4].[C18] AS [C28], 
    [UnionAll4].[C19] AS [C29], 
    [UnionAll4].[C20] AS [C30], 
    [UnionAll4].[C21] AS [C31], 
    [UnionAll4].[C22] AS [C32], 
    [UnionAll4].[C23] AS [C33], 
    [UnionAll4].[C24] AS [C34], 
    [UnionAll4].[C25] AS [C35], 
    [UnionAll4].[C26] AS [C36], 
    [UnionAll4].[C27] AS [C37], 
    [UnionAll4].[C28] AS [C38], 
    [UnionAll4].[C29] AS [C39], 
    [UnionAll4].[C30] AS [C40], 
    [UnionAll4].[C31] AS [C41], 
    [UnionAll4].[C32] AS [C42], 
    [UnionAll4].[C33] AS [C43], 
    [UnionAll4].[C34] AS [C44], 
    [UnionAll4].[C35] AS [C45], 
    [UnionAll4].[C36] AS [C46], 
    [UnionAll4].[C37] AS [C47], 
    [UnionAll4].[C38] AS [C48], 
    [UnionAll4].[C39] AS [C49], 
    [UnionAll4].[C40] AS [C50], 
    [UnionAll4].[C41] AS [C51], 
    [UnionAll4].[C42] AS [C52], 
    [UnionAll4].[C43] AS [C53], 
    [UnionAll4].[C44] AS [C54], 
    [UnionAll4].[C45] AS [C55], 
    [UnionAll4].[C46] AS [C56], 
    [UnionAll4].[C47] AS [C57], 
    [UnionAll4].[C48] AS [C58], 
    [UnionAll4].[C49] AS [C59], 
    [UnionAll4].[C50] AS [C60], 
    [UnionAll4].[C51] AS [C61], 
    [UnionAll4].[C52] AS [C62], 
    [UnionAll4].[C53] AS [C63], 
    [UnionAll4].[C54] AS [C64], 
    [UnionAll4].[C55] AS [C65], 
    [UnionAll4].[C56] AS [C66], 
    [UnionAll4].[C57] AS [C67], 
    [UnionAll4].[C58] AS [C68], 
    [UnionAll4].[C59] AS [C69], 
    [UnionAll4].[C60] AS [C70], 
    [UnionAll4].[C61] AS [C71], 
    [UnionAll4].[C62] AS [C72], 
    [UnionAll4].[C63] AS [C73], 
    [UnionAll4].[C64] AS [C74], 
    [UnionAll4].[C65] AS [C75], 
    [UnionAll4].[C66] AS [C76], 
    [UnionAll4].[C67] AS [C77], 
    [UnionAll4].[C68] AS [C78], 
    [UnionAll4].[C69] AS [C79], 
    [UnionAll4].[C70] AS [C80]
    FROM  (SELECT 
        CASE WHEN ([UnionAll1].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1], 
        [Limit1].[Id1] AS [Id], 
        [Limit1].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
        [Limit1].[Description1] AS [Description], 
        [Limit1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
        [Limit1].[BeginDate] AS [BeginDate], 
        [Limit1].[EndDate] AS [EndDate], 
        [Limit1].[Deadline] AS [Deadline], 
        [Limit1].[AuditTypeId] AS [AuditTypeId], 
        [Limit1].[Id2] AS [Id2], 
        [Limit1].[Description2] AS [Description1], 
        [UnionAll1].[Id] AS [C2], 
        [UnionAll1].[Id1] AS [C3], 
        [UnionAll1].[Description] AS [C4], 
        [UnionAll1].[AuditId] AS [C5], 
        [UnionAll1].[PhaseTypeId] AS [C6], 
        [UnionAll1].[BeginDate] AS [C7], 
        [UnionAll1].[EndDate] AS [C8], 
        [UnionAll1].[Deadline] AS [C9], 
        [UnionAll1].[Id2] AS [C10], 
        [UnionAll1].[Description1] AS [C11], 
        [UnionAll1].[C1] AS [C12], 
        [UnionAll1].[Id3] AS [C13], 
        [UnionAll1].[UserActionId] AS [C14], 
        [UnionAll1].[PhaseId] AS [C15], 
        [UnionAll1].[UserId] AS [C16], 
        [UnionAll1].[OwnerId] AS [C17], 
        [UnionAll1].[DiscretionKey] AS [C18], 
        [UnionAll1].[DiscretionValue] AS [C19], 
        [UnionAll1].[WorkflowId] AS [C20], 
        [UnionAll1].[RoleId] AS [C21], 
        [UnionAll1].[AuditResourceId] AS [C22], 
        [UnionAll1].[CostCenterId] AS [C23], 
        [UnionAll1].[UserActionStatus] AS [C24], 
        [UnionAll1].[CreationDate] AS [C25], 
        [UnionAll1].[LastModificationDate] AS [C26], 
        [UnionAll1].[C2] AS [C27], 
        [UnionAll1].[C3] AS [C28], 
        [UnionAll1].[C4] AS [C29], 
        [UnionAll1].[C5] AS [C30], 
        [UnionAll1].[C6] AS [C31], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C32], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C33], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C34], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C35], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C36], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C37], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C38], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C39], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C40], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C41], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C42], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C43], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C44], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C45], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C46], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C47], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C48], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C49], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C50], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C51], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C52], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C53], 
        CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C54], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C55], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C56], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C57], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C58], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C59], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C60], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C61], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C62], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C63], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C64], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C65], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C66], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C67], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C68], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C69], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C70]
        FROM   (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id1], [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description1], [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], [Extent1].[BeginDate] AS [BeginDate], [Extent1].[EndDate] AS [EndDate], [Extent1].[Deadline] AS [Deadline], [Extent1].[AuditTypeId] AS [AuditTypeId], [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id2], [Extent2].[Description] AS [Description2]
            FROM  [Aura].[Audit] AS [Extent1]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [Aura].[AuditType] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[AuditTypeId] = [Extent2].[Id]
            WHERE [Extent1].[EndDate] IS NULL ) AS [Limit1]
        OUTER APPLY  (SELECT 
            CASE WHEN ([Extent5].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1], 
            [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id1], 
            [Extent3].[Description] AS [Description], 
            [Extent3].[AuditId] AS [AuditId], 
            [Extent3].[PhaseTypeId] AS [PhaseTypeId], 
            [Extent3].[BeginDate] AS [BeginDate], 
            [Extent3].[EndDate] AS [EndDate], 
            [Extent3].[Deadline] AS [Deadline], 
            [Extent4].[Id] AS [Id2], 
            [Extent4].[Description] AS [Description1], 
            [Extent5].[Id] AS [Id3], 
            [Extent5].[UserActionId] AS [UserActionId], 
            [Extent5].[PhaseId] AS [PhaseId], 
            [Extent5].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
            [Extent5].[OwnerId] AS [OwnerId], 
            [Extent5].[DiscretionKey] AS [DiscretionKey], 
            [Extent5].[DiscretionValue] AS [DiscretionValue], 
            [Extent5].[WorkflowId] AS [WorkflowId], 
            [Extent5].[RoleId] AS [RoleId], 
            [Extent5].[AuditResourceId] AS [AuditResourceId], 
            [Extent5].[CostCenterId] AS [CostCenterId], 
            [Extent5].[UserActionStatus] AS [UserActionStatus], 
            [Extent5].[CreationDate] AS [CreationDate], 
            [Extent5].[LastModificationDate] AS [LastModificationDate], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C3], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C4], 
            CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C5], 
            CAST(NULL AS bit) AS [C6]
            FROM   [Aura].[Phase] AS [Extent3]
            INNER JOIN [Aura].[PhaseType] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[PhaseTypeId] = [Extent4].[Id]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [Aura].[UserActionLog] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent3].[Id] = [Extent5].[PhaseId]
            WHERE [Limit1].[Id1] = [Extent3].[AuditId]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            2 AS [C1], 
            [Extent6].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Extent6].[Id] AS [Id1], 
            [Extent6].[Description] AS [Description], 
            [Extent6].[AuditId] AS [AuditId], 
            [Extent6].[PhaseTypeId] AS [PhaseTypeId], 
            [Extent6].[BeginDate] AS [BeginDate], 
            [Extent6].[EndDate] AS [EndDate], 
            [Extent6].[Deadline] AS [Deadline], 
            [Extent7].[Id] AS [Id2], 
            [Extent7].[Description] AS [Description1], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C3], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C4], 
            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C5], 
            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C6], 
            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C7], 
            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C8], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C9], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C10], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C11], 
            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C12], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C13], 
            CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C14], 
            CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C15], 
            [Extent8].[Id] AS [Id3], 
            [Extent8].[ReminderTypeId] AS [ReminderTypeId], 
            [Extent8].[PhaseId] AS [PhaseId], 
            [Extent8].[DueDate] AS [DueDate], 
            [Extent8].[Sent] AS [Sent]
            FROM   [Aura].[Phase] AS [Extent6]
            INNER JOIN [Aura].[PhaseType] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent6].[PhaseTypeId] = [Extent7].[Id]
            INNER JOIN [Aura].[Reminder] AS [Extent8] ON [Extent6].[Id] = [Extent8].[PhaseId]
            WHERE [Limit1].[Id1] = [Extent6].[AuditId]) AS [UnionAll1]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        2 AS [C1], 
        [Limit2].[Id3] AS [Id], 
        [Limit2].[Id3] AS [Id1], 
        [Limit2].[Description3] AS [Description], 
        [Limit2].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
        [Limit2].[BeginDate] AS [BeginDate], 
        [Limit2].[EndDate] AS [EndDate], 
        [Limit2].[Deadline] AS [Deadline], 
        [Limit2].[AuditTypeId] AS [AuditTypeId], 
        [Limit2].[Id4] AS [Id2], 
        [Limit2].[Description4] AS [Description1], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C3], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C4], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C5], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C6], 
        CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C7], 
        CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C8], 
        CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C9], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C10], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C11], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C12], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C13], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C14], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C15], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C16], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C17], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C18], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C19], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C20], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C21], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C22], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C23], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C24], 
        CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C25], 
        CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C26], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C27], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C28], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C29], 
        CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C30], 
        CAST(NULL AS bit) AS [C31], 
        [UnionAll2].[Id] AS [C32], 
        [UnionAll2].[Id1] AS [C33], 
        [UnionAll2].[AuditId] AS [C34], 
        [UnionAll2].[ResourceId] AS [C35], 
        [UnionAll2].[Id2] AS [C36], 
        [UnionAll2].[Name] AS [C37], 
        [UnionAll2].[C1] AS [C38], 
        [UnionAll2].[Id3] AS [C39], 
        [UnionAll2].[Id4] AS [C40], 
        [UnionAll2].[OwnerId] AS [C41], 
        [UnionAll2].[OwnerTypeId] AS [C42], 
        [UnionAll2].[AuditResourceId] AS [C43], 
        [UnionAll2].[DelegateForId] AS [C44], 
        [UnionAll2].[Id5] AS [C45], 
        [UnionAll2].[UserId] AS [C46], 
        [UnionAll2].[FirstName] AS [C47], 
        [UnionAll2].[LastName] AS [C48], 
        [UnionAll2].[Email] AS [C49], 
        [UnionAll2].[C2] AS [C50], 
        [UnionAll2].[C3] AS [C51], 
        [UnionAll2].[C4] AS [C52], 
        [UnionAll2].[C5] AS [C53], 
        [UnionAll2].[C6] AS [C54], 
        [UnionAll2].[C7] AS [C55], 
        [UnionAll2].[C8] AS [C56], 
        [UnionAll2].[C9] AS [C57], 
        [UnionAll2].[C10] AS [C58], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C59], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C60], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C61], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C62], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C63], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C64], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C65], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C66], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C67], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C68], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C69], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C70]
        FROM   (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent9].[Id] AS [Id3], [Extent9].[Description] AS [Description3], [Extent9].[UserId] AS [UserId], [Extent9].[BeginDate] AS [BeginDate], [Extent9].[EndDate] AS [EndDate], [Extent9].[Deadline] AS [Deadline], [Extent9].[AuditTypeId] AS [AuditTypeId], [Extent10].[Id] AS [Id4], [Extent10].[Description] AS [Description4]
            FROM  [Aura].[Audit] AS [Extent9]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [Aura].[AuditType] AS [Extent10] ON [Extent9].[AuditTypeId] = [Extent10].[Id]
            WHERE [Extent9].[EndDate] IS NULL ) AS [Limit2]
        CROSS APPLY  (SELECT 
            CASE WHEN ([Join8].[Id5] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1], 
            [Extent11].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Extent11].[Id] AS [Id1], 
            [Extent11].[AuditId] AS [AuditId], 
            [Extent11].[ResourceId] AS [ResourceId], 
            [Extent12].[Id] AS [Id2], 
            [Extent12].[Name] AS [Name], 
            [Join8].[Id5] AS [Id3], 
            [Join8].[Id5] AS [Id4], 
            [Join8].[OwnerId] AS [OwnerId], 
            [Join8].[OwnerTypeId] AS [OwnerTypeId], 
            [Join8].[AuditResourceId] AS [AuditResourceId], 
            [Join8].[DelegateForId] AS [DelegateForId], 
            [Join8].[Id6] AS [Id5], 
            [Join8].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
            [Join8].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
            [Join8].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
            [Join8].[Email] AS [Email], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C3], 
            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C4], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C5], 
            CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C6], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C7], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C8], 
            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C9], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C10]
            FROM   [Aura].[AuditResource] AS [Extent11]
            INNER JOIN [Aura].[Resource] AS [Extent12] ON [Extent11].[ResourceId] = [Extent12].[Id]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent13].[Id] AS [Id5], [Extent13].[OwnerId] AS [OwnerId], [Extent13].[OwnerTypeId] AS [OwnerTypeId], [Extent13].[AuditResourceId] AS [AuditResourceId], [Extent13].[DelegateForId] AS [DelegateForId], [Extent14].[Id] AS [Id6], [Extent14].[UserId] AS [UserId], [Extent14].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], [Extent14].[LastName] AS [LastName], [Extent14].[Email] AS [Email]
                FROM  [Aura].[ResourceOwner] AS [Extent13]
                INNER JOIN [Aura].[Owner] AS [Extent14] ON [Extent13].[OwnerId] = [Extent14].[Id] ) AS [Join8] ON [Extent11].[Id] = [Join8].[AuditResourceId]
            WHERE [Limit2].[Id3] = [Extent11].[AuditId]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            2 AS [C1], 
            [Extent15].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Extent15].[Id] AS [Id1], 
            [Extent15].[AuditId] AS [AuditId], 
            [Extent15].[ResourceId] AS [ResourceId], 
            [Extent16].[Id] AS [Id2], 
            [Extent16].[Name] AS [Name], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C3], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C4], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C5], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C6], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C7], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C8], 
            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C9], 
            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C10], 
            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C11], 
            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C12], 
            [Join11].[Id7] AS [Id3], 
            [Join11].[Id7] AS [Id4], 
            [Join11].[Name] AS [Name1], 
            [Join11].[AuditResourceId] AS [AuditResourceId], 
            [Join11].[CreationDate] AS [CreationDate], 
            CASE WHEN ([Join11].[Id8] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C13], 
            [Join11].[Id8] AS [Id5], 
            [Join11].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
            [Join11].[UserFileId] AS [UserFileId]
            FROM   [Aura].[AuditResource] AS [Extent15]
            INNER JOIN [Aura].[Resource] AS [Extent16] ON [Extent15].[ResourceId] = [Extent16].[Id]
            INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent17].[Id] AS [Id7], [Extent17].[Name] AS [Name], [Extent17].[AuditResourceId] AS [AuditResourceId], [Extent17].[CreationDate] AS [CreationDate], [Extent18].[Id] AS [Id8], [Extent18].[UserId] AS [UserId], [Extent18].[UserFileId] AS [UserFileId]
                FROM  [Aura].[UserFile] AS [Extent17]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [Aura].[UserList] AS [Extent18] ON [Extent17].[Id] = [Extent18].[UserFileId] ) AS [Join11] ON [Extent15].[Id] = [Join11].[AuditResourceId]
            WHERE [Limit2].[Id3] = [Extent15].[AuditId]) AS [UnionAll2]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        3 AS [C1], 
        [Limit3].[Id9] AS [Id], 
        [Limit3].[Id9] AS [Id1], 
        [Limit3].[Description5] AS [Description], 
        [Limit3].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
        [Limit3].[BeginDate] AS [BeginDate], 
        [Limit3].[EndDate] AS [EndDate], 
        [Limit3].[Deadline] AS [Deadline], 
        [Limit3].[AuditTypeId] AS [AuditTypeId], 
        [Limit3].[Id10] AS [Id2], 
        [Limit3].[Description6] AS [Description1], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C3], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C4], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C5], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C6], 
        CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C7], 
        CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C8], 
        CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C9], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C10], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C11], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C12], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C13], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C14], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C15], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C16], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C17], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C18], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C19], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C20], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C21], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C22], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C23], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C24], 
        CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C25], 
        CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C26], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C27], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C28], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C29], 
        CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C30], 
        CAST(NULL AS bit) AS [C31], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C32], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C33], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C34], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C35], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C36], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C37], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C38], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C39], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C40], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C41], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C42], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C43], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C44], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C45], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C46], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C47], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C48], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C49], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C50], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C51], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C52], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C53], 
        CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C54], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C55], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C56], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C57], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C58], 
        [Join14].[Id11] AS [Id3], 
        [Join14].[Id11] AS [Id4], 
        [Join14].[AuditId] AS [AuditId], 
        [Join14].[CostCenterManagerId] AS [CostCenterManagerId], 
        [Join14].[DelegateForId] AS [DelegateForId], 
        [Join14].[Id12] AS [Id5], 
        [Join14].[UserId] AS [UserId1], 
        [Join14].[CostCenterId] AS [CostCenterId], 
        [Join14].[CostCenterName] AS [CostCenterName], 
        [Join14].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
        [Join14].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
        [Join14].[Email] AS [Email]
        FROM   (SELECT TOP (1) [Extent19].[Id] AS [Id9], [Extent19].[Description] AS [Description5], [Extent19].[UserId] AS [UserId], [Extent19].[BeginDate] AS [BeginDate], [Extent19].[EndDate] AS [EndDate], [Extent19].[Deadline] AS [Deadline], [Extent19].[AuditTypeId] AS [AuditTypeId], [Extent20].[Id] AS [Id10], [Extent20].[Description] AS [Description6]
            FROM  [Aura].[Audit] AS [Extent19]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [Aura].[AuditType] AS [Extent20] ON [Extent19].[AuditTypeId] = [Extent20].[Id]
            WHERE [Extent19].[EndDate] IS NULL ) AS [Limit3]
        INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent21].[Id] AS [Id11], [Extent21].[AuditId] AS [AuditId], [Extent21].[CostCenterManagerId] AS [CostCenterManagerId], [Extent21].[DelegateForId] AS [DelegateForId], [Extent22].[Id] AS [Id12], [Extent22].[UserId] AS [UserId], [Extent22].[CostCenterId] AS [CostCenterId], [Extent22].[CostCenterName] AS [CostCenterName], [Extent22].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], [Extent22].[LastName] AS [LastName], [Extent22].[Email] AS [Email]
            FROM  [Aura].[AuditCostCenterManager] AS [Extent21]
            INNER JOIN [Aura].[CostCenterManager] AS [Extent22] ON [Extent21].[CostCenterManagerId] = [Extent22].[Id] ) AS [Join14] ON [Limit3].[Id9] = [Join14].[AuditId]) AS [UnionAll4]
    ORDER BY [UnionAll4].[Id1] ASC, [UnionAll4].[Id2] ASC, [UnionAll4].[C1] ASC, [UnionAll4].[C3] ASC, [UnionAll4].[C10] ASC, [UnionAll4].[C12] ASC, [UnionAll4].[C33] ASC, [UnionAll4].[C36] ASC, [UnionAll4].[C38] ASC, [UnionAll4].[C51] ASC, [UnionAll4].[C55] ASC


-- Executing at 25/10/2016 16:21:14 +02:00

-- Completed in 847 ms with result: SqlDataReader
```

Comment: The easiest first step would be to replace `SingleOrDefault` with `FirstOrDefault`.  Do you REALLY need to search every record to prove that it is unique?  Most likely not, particularly if you are properly using primary keys.

Comment: **but I don't see how I can do this kind of complex query in Dapper**  Not sure what this means? Have you tried converting your LINQ expression to a SQL query ?

Comment: @Shyju I did not yet but it's the nesting of the mapping in Dapper that scares me... I will try and work something out and post back here.

Comment: The query you posted might be generated from EF. Why not write your own query. What nesting of the mapping is scaring you ?

Comment: @DavidL Hi, I tried that and shaved of some seconds but nothing noticeable, but a good point!

Comment: @grmbl It isn't just about shaving seconds although any improvement is great, it's also about best practice and not hammering your database when not necessary.  Very rarely is `SingleOrDefault` the most appropriate choice.  In your case, i would ask yourself what is ***absolutely necessary*** in terms of data and then modify what data is returned to match.  Most of the time, when optimizing for a page with Dapper, you can cut out large amounts of data simply because it is no longer needed.  The generated EF query most likely materializes far more than you actually need.

Comment: @Shyju I need to break down the query first and then compose 1 single object from it. I will make an attempt at it. :)

Comment: @DavidL I agree. + the design of the application requires 1 object to bind to so here's that. I will review the callers requirements, optimize (with or without Dapper) and post back here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EntityFramework performs badly when using multiple includes, as optimizing the resulting query is very slow. The recommendation by the [Performance Considerations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853(v=vs.113).aspx#8-2-2-Performance-concerns-with-multiple-Includes) page is to break up the query:

```
// First get the max id
int auditId = context.Audits.Max(aa => aa.Id);
// Now, pre-load the related entities
context.Phases.Where(p => p.Audit.Id == auditId && p.Audit.EndDate == null).Load();
context.UserActionLogs.Where(l => l.Phase.Audit.Id == auditId && l.Phase.Audit.EndDate == null).Load();
// ... do the same for all related properties
// And finally get the resulting object
return context.Audits
        .Where(a => a.Id == auditId && a.EndDate == null)
        .SingleOrDefault();
```

Here you are trading off slow query compilation and large data payload against more (but smaller) queries.

Do note however, that this only works on queries with tracking enabled.